# Is there a better way to invoke a table-producing function other than calling `val` all the times?

Tags: java, kotlin, jooq

I'm calling a function from the database, named `some_table_generating_function` for the sake of simplicity, in order to cast the query into a select statement returning `Field<Array<UUID>>`, it forces me to use the `val` function of the DSL, and it creates a lot of boilerplate for doing a simple function invocation.

The following example works, but it seems to be overusing the `val` function, do you have any suggestions to cleanse this piece of code?

```kotlin
context
  .select()
  .from(
    select(
      // fields to be selected
    )
      .from(
        Public.SOME_TABLE_GENERATING_FUNCTION(
          `val`(someString.capitalise()),
          `val`(someInt),
          `val`(BigDecimal(someDecimalString)),
          `val`(someInt),
          `val`(BigDecimal(anotherDecimalString)),
          `val`(BigDecimal(yetAnotherDecimalString)),
          `val`(anotherInt),
          `val`(someLong),
          `val`(anotherLong),
          // the important bit: uuid[] parameter expected for this parameter
          field(
            "ARRAY({0})::uuid[]",
            select(A_TABLE.UUID.cast(String::class.java))
              .from(A_TABLE)
              .innerJoin(ANOTHER_TABLE)
              .on(A_TABLE.UUID.eq(ANOTHER_TABLE.UUID))
              .where(
                // additional conditions
              )
          ) as Field<Array<UUID>>
        )
      )
      .join(THE_TABLE)
      .asTable("inner_query")
  )
  .where(
    // additional conditions
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Background on the availability of convenience overloads

jOOQ's API can't overload all possible combinations of `Tn` vs `Field<Tn>` for larger numbers of `n` where `n` is the number of function parameters. For example:

- 1 parameter = 2 overloads (`f(T1)` and `f(F<T1>)`
- 2 parameters = 4 overloads (`f(T1, T2)`, `f(T1, F<T2>)`, `f(F<T1>, T2)`, `f(F<T1>, F<T2>)`
- 3 parameters = 8 overloads
- n parameters = 2^n overloads

While the DSL API often provides complete overloads for 2 parameters, it stops at 3 parameters, offering only 2 overloads in total:

- An overload accepting *only* bind values
- An overload accepting *only* expressions

It is the same with convenience overloads of generated user defined functions.

#### Possibility of a more verbose call syntax

Ordinary routines support both the convenience syntax and a more verbose call syntax:

```java
// Convenience call
Routines.ordinaryRoutine(1, 2)

// Verbose way to call the routine, equivalent to the above
val r = OrdinaryRoutine()
r.param1 = 1
r.param2 = 2
```

This currently isn't available for table valued functions, which only know the "convenience syntax". Might be worth looking into generating alternatives to calling table valued functions:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14508

#### Workarounds

- You could create an auxiliary function that calls your function but accepts the first set of parameters in the form of a UDT (`CREATE TYPE`), so you have to wrap the single UDT argument in `DSL.val()` only a single time. This doesn't scale too well in terms of function API design, but it works around this problem
- You could use plain SQL templating for the function call (`from("f(?, ?, ... {0})", someString.capitalise(), someInt, ..., field(...))`), since you're already using a plain SQL template. This won't be type safe, though.
- You could [extend the `JavaGenerator`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/) to generate an extra overload for your specific case

Personally, I don't find any of these workarounds very practical. Since you probably don't have this case very often, I'd stick with the original call using explicit `val` calls